# Scale HTML5 Canvas to div width and height

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

In my application i have div that styled with twitter bootstrap like this :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

the canvas is placeholder of some large images.i need a way to scale image to width and height of this div or if not exactly scale to width and height of div , scale must create a very small scroll bar for div. the div has `overflow:scroll` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using bootstrap, you can do it with jquery:

```
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var $parent = $canvas.parent();
$canvas.width($parent.width());
$canvas.height($parent.height());
```

Comment: Be sure to resize the width & height proportionally (maintaining the original aspect ratio) or the canvas content will be distorted (stretched).

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like a non-javascript answer, you can make this happen in CSS:

```
.col-md-12{
  position:relative; //make sure this is part of your col-md style
}

#canvas{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
}
```

I'm assuming that there is styling that is setting the height of your .col-md-12 div elsewhere.

Comment: Be aware, that this will not change the width and height of the canvas, but it will `transform` the width and height. That means its content will look distorted / streched.

Answer (score 4):

Get the width and height of the div using `JavaScript` and then set the canvas height and width with these values.

For instance:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var divHeight = document.getElementById('yourDiv').clientHeight;
var divWidth = document.getElementById('yourDiv').clientWidth;

canvas.height = divHeight;
canvas.width = divWidth;
```

You could add this to a `resize` event handler so when the `div` height/width scales it invokes the above code.

Comment: when i use this way i can't see my image in canvas.